# Best practices regarding Flask CRUD Views

Tags: python, view, flask, crud

I am currently working on a CRUD application that will end up spanning a rather large database and I would like to go about it using best practices.

When I design a Flask View I currently put all functions in one view like this.

```
@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user', methods=['GET'])
@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user/<string:function>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user/<string:function>/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userView(lang=None, id=None, function=None):
    if function == None:
        pass
    elif function == 'delete':
        pass        
    else:
        if function == 'update':
            pass
        elif function == 'new':
            pass
```

As you can imagine this view can become rather large when taking all the db functionality into consideration (relationships, selectfield choice generation, multi-tenancy controls etc.).

Another way to accomplish this same task would be to build five views like this.

```
@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user', methods=['GET'])
def getUsers(lang=None):
    pass

@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user', methods=['POST'])
def newUsers(lang=None):
    pass

@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def getUser(lang=None, id=None):
    pass

@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def deleteUser(lang=None, id=None):
    pass

@userBlueprint.route('/<string:lang>/user/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def modifyUser(lang=None, id=None):
    pass
```

The downside here of course is that I would need to put in a lot of repetitive code.

Is either method considered "best practice" and if not, is there a third option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in instrument for it is flask [method views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/views/#method-views-for-apis), they are designed specifically to help you implement different object actions in different functions:

```
class UserAPI(MethodView):

    def get(self, user_id):
        if user_id is None:
            # return a list of users
            pass
        else:
            # expose a single user
            pass

    def post(self):
        # create a new user
        pass

    def delete(self, user_id):
        # delete a single user
        pass

    def put(self, user_id):
        # update a single user
        pass

user_view = UserAPI.as_view('user_api')
app.add_url_rule('<string:lang>/user/', defaults={'user_id': None}, view_func=user_view, methods=['GET'])
app.add_url_rule('<string:lang>/user/', view_func=user_view, methods=['POST'])
app.add_url_rule('<string:lang>/user/<int:user_id>', view_func=user_view, methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
```

It will be quite easy to implement several views for different tables: create BaseAPI method view and subclass from it. Getting/updating/deleting an object may be similar for different tables.

You may also look at implementation of CRUD in [flask-admin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/model/base.py#L1817) package. Its routes are grouped this way:

- `<string:tablename>/` (GET) — Showing list of objects
- `<string:tablename>/new/` (GET, POST) — Showing form for creating an object / Creating an object
- `<string:tablename>/edit/` (GET, POST) - Showing form for editing an object / Updating an object
- `<string:tablename>/delete/` (POST) - Deleting an object